# 'SolidBrush' parameter type is not valid for formatting property 'Foreground'. Parameter name: value

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, textrange

I try change color text RickTextBox wpf in invoke method . But i get some trouble . My trouble is

> **'SolidBrush' parameter type is not valid for formatting property 'Foreground'. Parameter name: value**

**My code**

```
MethodInvoker action = delegate
{
    TextRange textRange = new TextRange(RtTextProcess.Document.ContentStart, RtTextProcess.Document.ContentEnd);

    if (txtColor == null) txtColor = Color.Black;

    int start = textRange.Text.Length;
    var txt = string.Concat(DateTime.Now.ToString(), " : ", text);

    if (textRange.Text == "\r\n")
    {
        textRange.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {
        textRange.Text += txt.ToString();
    }

    TextPointer start1 = textRange.Start.GetPositionAtOffset(start, LogicalDirection.Forward);
    TextPointer end = textRange.Start.GetPositionAtOffset(txt.Length, LogicalDirection.Backward);
    if (start1 != null && end != null)
    {
        RtTextProcess.Selection.Select(start1, end);
    }

    // My error is here                     
    textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red);

    string rtb = RtTextProcess.Selection.Text;
};

RtTextProcess.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
```

Please help me

**Thanks !**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the WPF `System.Windows.Media.Brushes` class instead of `System.Drawing.Brushes` from WinForms:

```
// using System.Drawing; --- remove this
using System.Windows.Media;
...

textRange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red);
```